# c++ libdl.so: Can't open shared library in 32bit application

Tags: c++, linux, 32bit-64bit, libdl

I am writing a little project in which I want to call a function from a shared library. For that I want to use `libdl.so`'s `dlopen()` function.

I have everything set up so that it will work just fine when I build and run it as a 64bit application. However as soon as I am compiling it as a 32bit application and then try to run it, it won't be able to load any library.

`dlopen()` simply returns null and a call to `dlerror()` reveals

> libtbbmalloc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Now I am guessing that I have to somehow install a 32bit version of that library but I can't find it in the package manager and what I have found online isn't too helpful either.

Does someone know that the problem is and/or how I could fic it?

---

I am building my project via `cmake v3.10` and in the CMakeLists.txt I am using this instructions for 32bit:

```
set_target_properties(clib PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
target_link_libraries(clib /usr/lib32/libdl.so)
```

I have installed the package `g++-multilib` and my `g++` version is `7.3.0`.

I am attempting to build my program on Linux Mint 18.3 (6bit).

Comment: Have you tried to install package `libtbb-dev:i386`?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond That did the trick (partly). After having installed this package I had to also install the `libz-dev:i386` package and now it works. If you add an answer with this information I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, but it fine as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Lorinczy Zsigmond in the comments, I was able to find the problem: I had to install the packages `libtbb-dev:i836` and `libz-dev:i836` in order for the function loading to work properly.